# My code about polygon is not working

Tags: java, applet, awt

i had a problem about polygons , i wrote my code but it is not working.Possibly i missed something  because i don't have any error message .

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class drawPloygon extends Applet {
int  [] x  ={20,20,30,40,40};
int y []={40,20,30,20,40};


public void paintPolygon (Graphics g ){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillPolygon(x, y, 5);


}

}
```

Comment: you didnt override the paint method, your paintPolygon method is never being called

Comment: when i override it , it gives me error message to  remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what u mean in your comment that it asks you to remove your code... but this is what you should add and this should work:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    paintPolygon(g);
}
```

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g){ paintPolygon(g); ..` should honor the paint chain, by instead being.. `public void paint(Graphics g){ super.paint(g); paintPolygon(g); ..`